# Commands that renew helper commands within the given scope: question about design

Tags: macros, latex3, renewcommand, learning

My question is about the design of commands that redefine other helper commands. In order to ask my question, I need to give a small set-up in order to describe what I mean. Let's take some helper commands from my personal preamble, with some minor changes for this question:

```latex
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parenth}{(}{)}

\providecommand{\intvar}{}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\integral}{s m m e{_^}}{%
    \renewcommand{\intvar}{#2}
    \int%
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\parenth*{#3}}{#3}%
    \odif{#2}%
}

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\fourier}{s m m m E{_^}{{-\infty}{\infty}}}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \integral*{#2}{{#4}e^{-2\pi i{#2}{#3}}}_{#5}^{#6}%
    }{%
        \integral{#2}{{#4}e^{-2\pi i{#2}{#3}}}_{#5}^{#6}%
    }%
}
```

To save you the trouble of deciphering the commands, they take on the form `\integral{variable}{body}_{from}^{to}` and `\fourier{var from}{var to}{body}_{from}^{to}`, where the sub and super-scripts are optional. Now, notice my use of the command `\intvar`. I have added it to the `\integral` command definition for the sake of this question. Its purpose is to allow the user to get the variable of integration for an integral. As an example:

```latex
\begin{gather*}
    \integral{x}{f(\intvar) g(\intvar)}_{0}^{1}\\
    \fourier{t}{\xi}{f(\intvar)}
\end{gather*}
```

Gives us:

[image]

And if we change the integration variable, but not the body:

```latex
\begin{gather*}
    \integral{z}{f(\intvar) g(\intvar)}_{0}^{1}\\
    \fourier{\theta}{\xi}{f(\intvar)}
\end{gather*}
```

We get as we expect:

[image]

So, my question involves cases like this, where you can use, say `\integral`, within another `\integral` command (or derived command, as is the case with `\fourier`). Doing so will obviously mean that `\intvar` takes on the variable of that "level", as expected. As an example:

```latex
\begin{gather*}
    \integral{x}{f(\intvar)\integral{y}{g(\intvar)}}
\end{gather*}
```

Giving:

[image]

This code, however, is still rather dangerous and can produce cases where the document will never compile. Eg, putting `\intvar` here never compiles: `\integral{x}{\fourier{\intvar}{...}{...}}` since it attempts to set the value of `\intval` to `\intval`, which is then recursive. (How would this be handled so that this situation could never occur?)

My question: How do you correctly write macros with these kinds of inner-defined commands? In honesty, I have never thought of such a case of needing this. But this example is a fun and interesting one I thought of that I would like to come to understand more of.

Would this be done through more careful design considerations and testing, or through more advanced expl3? Are there packages that help to do these kinds of tasks?

Additionally, could you design a case where you can reference an `\intvar` from a higher level? For example, if I wanted to reference the variable of integration for the integral surrounding the current integral scope. In this case, `\intvar` would only be for that scope's integral variable. Is this something that can be done without extreme difficulty? And if so, how would someone even go about defining such a command (as in, what tools do they use: a package, lower-level macros, etc)? Are there other considerations that would have to be made?

Comment: You may be interested in TeX's grouping mechanism which is described in... maybe TeXbook chapter 5. That having said programming in TeX is usually complicated anyway

Comment: @user202729 Thanks! I haven't seen that term before, so it will likely be a new read. Thanks! Edit: Having looked at it, I have and just forgot the terminology lol

Comment: I would add a `\begingroup...\endgroup` scope to your `\integral` command so that `\intvar` is only in scope between `\int` and `d...` currently it is defined for all following  code (so nested instances will only accidentally work)

Comment: so it may be a better idea to just explicitly write out what you want (`x` instead of `\intvar`) anyway. That having said what does the other example even mean (you can't integrate over the same variable twice right?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I have never considered using that in this example. I have seen that before, but never needed it myself. I will give it a think to understand how it would help.

Comment: @user202729 If you are talking about the non-compiling example, I didn't really put much thought into that. I just wanted something that breaks with the provided setup. Edit: I removed part of that example in place of `...` to avoid pointless confusion

Comment: you need it otherwise this is simply not true "Doing so will obviously mean that \intvar takes on the variable of that "level", as expected."  there is no level or scope implied by  macro definition

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahhh, yes, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping.

Also code duplication can be reduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\odif}{\mathop{}\!d}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parenth}{(}{)}

\providecommand{\intvar}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\integral}{s m m e{_^}}{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\intvar}{#2}%
    \int
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\parenth*{#3}}{#3}%
    \odif#2%
    \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fourier}{s m m m E{_^}{{-\infty}{\infty}}}{%
    \expanded{\integral\IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}%
    {#2}{{#4}e^{-2\pi i{#2}{#3}}}_{#5}^{#6}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \integral{x}{f(\intvar) g(\intvar)}_{0}^{1} \\
    \fourier{t}{\xi}{f(\intvar)} \\
    \integral{x}{f(\intvar)\integral{y}{g(\intvar)}} \\
    \integral*{x}{f(\intvar) + g(\intvar)}_{0}^{1} \\
    \fourier*{t}{\xi}{f(\intvar)} \\
    \integral{x}{f(\intvar)\integral*{y}{g(\intvar)+2}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I cannot recommend using `\parenth*` indiscriminately, though.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I haven't seen that kind of refactoring. That is very interesting. I will admit that the `\fourier` command is something I only cooked up in the past day or two in order to reduce my own typing, so I haven't given any time to think about it's implementation. As for your final comment, can you elaborate? If you mean to say using `\parenth*` in the integral should be used only when needed, then that is exactly how I use it. I only do it when I have many large integral/summation combinations, so it is simply a helpful boilerplate remover, if necessary.